# PHP curl extension not enabling

Tags: 18.04, php, curl

I'm using the ondrej/php PPA and have been for a while with no issues but I recently upgraded to PHP 7.3 and I've hit a snag.

I uninstalled all reference of the previous version and installed 7.3 and everything else is working fine but curl is not showing up in my phpinfo, but it is installed and according to the phpinfo it can see the curl.ini file

I even tried reinstalling the curl extension but no dice, still not showing up.

if I do `apt list --installed | grep php` this is what comes back:

```
dh-php/bionic,bionic,now 0.34+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 all [installed,automatic]
libapache2-mod-php7.3/bionic,now 7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed]
php-common/bionic,bionic,now 2:69+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+2+php7.3 all [installed,automatic]
php-pear/bionic,bionic,now 1:1.10.8+submodules+notgz-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 all [installed,automatic]
php-uuid/bionic,now 1.0.4-6+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+10 amd64 [installed]
php-xml/bionic,bionic,now 2:7.3+69+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+2+php7.3 all [installed]
php7.3/bionic,bionic,now 7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 all [installed]
php7.3-cli/bionic,now 7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
php7.3-common/bionic,now 7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
php7.3-curl/bionic,now 7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed]
php7.3-dev/bionic,now 7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed]
php7.3-gd/bionic,now 7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed]
php7.3-intl/bionic,now 7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed]
php7.3-json/bionic,now 7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
php7.3-mbstring/bionic,now 7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed]
php7.3-mysql/bionic,now 7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed]
php7.3-opcache/bionic,now 7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
php7.3-readline/bionic,now 7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
php7.3-xml/bionic,now 7.3.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed]
pkg-php-tools/bionic,bionic,now 1.35ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
```

It's not showing up for either apache or cli.

I'm at a lost on what I can do to get curl working, I need it for one of my web apps.

Comment: Please provide the output of `apt list --installed | grep php` so we can see your PHP packages exactly.

Comment: If You have it installed You can enable it via command `sudo phpenmod curl`. Then verify by `php -m`.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz that didn't do it, still not showing up

Comment: @fkraiem I've updated my question with the results of that command

Comment: Nothing wrong there... Just in case, have you restarted Apache after installing/enabling the PHP curl module?

Comment: I did, it's also not showing up for cli

Comment: Edit the file `sudo nano /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini` and add there `extension=curl.so`. Then run the `php -m` again in terminal.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz that file already has that in there

Comment: I think I may have found the issue, it looks like a bad update with that PPA caused a few issues, I'm going to try their fix and see if that resolves things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was from a [bad update](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libidn2/+bug/1843507?comments=all) with the PPA. Once I followed the instructions everything started working. If it wasn't for me noticing my server hasn't updated in a while I wouldn't have stumbled upon this.